# How to get each exchange swap price using 0x api

Tags: 0x

I am able to call the 0x /swap/v1/quote? endpoint without any issue (I know that is not hard).  But passing in multiple exchanges, I thought, would return the swap prices on those exchanges.  But it only returns a single price.   Is it possible to return multiple prices from 0x or is it used for "best price"?

My code example:

```
  const multiExchangeQuote = async (inputToken, outputToken, value) => {
const exchangeList = '0x,Uniswap,Uniswap_V2,Eth2Dai,Kyber,Curve,Balancer, Balancer_V2,Bancor,mStable,Mooniswap,Swerve,SnowSwap,SushiSwap,Shell MultiHop, DODO,DODO_V2,CREAM,LiquidityProvider,CryptoCom,Linkswap,Lido,MakerPsm,KyberDMM,Smoothy,Component,Saddle,xSigma,Uniswap_V3,Curve_V2'
const params = {
  buyToken: 'DAI',
  sellToken: 'ETH',
  sellAmount: 0.05 * Math.pow(10, 18).toString(), // Always denominated in wei
  includedSources: exchangeList,
}
let response
try {
  response = await axios.get(
    `${URL}${qs.stringify(params)}`,
  )
} catch (err) {
  console.error(err)
}
console.log("Multi Exchange Quote",)
console.log(response.data);
//console.log("%O",response.data.sources)
```

}

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, 0x API is an aggregation service, so it's designed to return a *combined* quote across all sources available to it (not just best price). You can sometimes get the price from a single source by using the [`includedSources=`](https://docs.0x.org/0x-api-swap/api-references/get-swap-v1-quote#request) request param, but even that will get aggregated across different pools on that source, so it may not be what you're looking for.